# WebAssembly.instantiate() function

Tags: performance, overloading, arraybuffer, webassembly

Was exploring web assembly a bit since it is now natively in all major browsers. Having some questions regarding the `WebAssembly.instantiate()` exactly work.

Mozilla web docs state the following:

> The WebAssembly.instantiate() function allows you to compile and
>   instantiate WebAssembly code.

The function can be overloaded in the following formats:

1. `Promise<ResultObject> WebAssembly.instantiate(bufferSource, importObject);`
2. `Promise<WebAssembly.Instance> WebAssembly.instantiate(module, importObject);`

The secondary overload (in my above list) takes as a first argument an already-compiled WebAssembly Module. The first overload takes the WebAssembly binary code, in the form of a typed array or ArrayBuffer.

### Question:

1. Is the only way that these overloads differ is the format in which the Wasm is passed in as an argument?
2. Could there be any significant performance differences between these methods?